# char vs wchar_t vs char16_t vs char32_t (c++11)

Tags: c++, c++11

From what I understand, a `char` is safe to house ASCII characters whereas `char16_t` and `char32_t` are safe to house characters from unicode, one for the 16-bit variety and another for the 32-bit variety (Should I have said "a" instead of "the"?). But I'm then left wondering what the purpose behind the `wchar_t` is. Should I ever use that type in new code, or is it simply there to support old code? What was the purpose of `wchar_t` in old code if, from what I understand, its size had no guarantee to be bigger than a `char`? Clarification would be nice!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`char` is for 8-bit code units, `char16_t` is for 16-bit code units, and `char32_t` is for 32-bit code units. Any of these can be used for 'Unicode'; UTF-8 uses 8-bit code units, UTF-16 uses 16-bit code units, and UTF-32 uses 32-bit code units.

---

The guarantee made for `wchar_t` was that any character supported in a locale could be converted from `char` to `wchar_t`, and whatever representation was used for `char`, be it multiple bytes, shift codes, what have you, the `wchar_t` would be a single, distinct value. The purpose of this was that then you could manipulate `wchar_t` strings just like the simple algorithms used with ASCII.

For example, converting ascii to upper case goes like:

```
auto loc = std::locale("");

char s[] = "hello";
for (char &c : s) {
  c = toupper(c, loc);
}
```

But this won't handle converting all characters in UTF-8 to uppercase, or all characters in some other encoding like Shift-JIS. People wanted to be able to internationalize this code like so:

```
auto loc = std::locale("");

wchar_t s[] = L"hello";
for (wchar_t &c : s) {
  c = toupper(c, loc);
}
```

So every `wchar_t` is a 'character' and if it has an uppercase version then it can be directly converted. Unfortunately this doesn't really work all the time; For example there exist oddities in some languages such as the German letter ß where the uppercase version is actually the two characters SS instead of a single character.

So internationalized text handling is intrinsically harder than ASCII and cannot really be simplified in the way the designers of `wchar_t` intended. As such `wchar_t` and wide characters in general provide little value.

The only reason to use them is that they've been baked into some APIs and platforms. However, I prefer to stick to UTF-8 in my own code even when developing on such platforms, and to just convert at the API boundaries to whatever encoding is required.

Comment: I like your comment and Kuhl's comment, they both have unique information. I wish I could give two green checks. I'll have to think it over to decide who gets it. Is it standard protocol on stackoverflow to give no check in case of a tie?

Comment: *"the German letter ß where the uppercase version is actually the two characters SS"* - That's not quite accurate. The uppercase version of "ß" is "ẞ" (U+1E9E: Latin Capital Letter Sharp S). It was introduced with Unicode 5.1 (see [Tailored Casing Operations](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/#Tailored_Casing_Operations) for reference). While the default Unicode casing does uppercase "ß" to "SS", this really isn't the uppercase version.

Comment: @IInspectable Use of "SS" is not an invention of the Unicode casing algorithm. It is based on actual usage. Using "SS" and "SZ" have been the common practice and the Unicode algorithms were designed to respect that. From the Unicode documentation you link to "In particular, capital sharp s is intended for typographical representations of signage and uppercase titles, and other environments where users require the sharp s to be preserved in uppercase. **Overall, such usage is rare**."

Comment: @IInspectable But you're right, technically "ß" has no traditional uppercase, and use of "SS" or "SZ" comes from the fact that "ss" or "sz" is used whenever a "ß" character is unavailable (e.g. when writing German with a keyboard lacking the "ß" key). Since traditionally there's no capital ß the practice has been to capitalize the usual "ss" and "sz" substitutes to get the capital form of "ß".

Comment: ß traditionally doesn't have an uppercase, because it is not a letter, but a ligature of the traditional lowercase s (written as a vertical bar in fraktur) and a lowercase z. That's hy it's called esszet is german. The capital "ẞ" introduced with Unicode 5.1 is there only for titel casing. Uppercasing in actual text shall never use it.

Comment: Your example shows a limitation of an _algorithm_, not the character set.  It doesn't explain why `wchar_t` can't just be an alias of one of the sized character types, analogous to `long`.

Answer (score 26):

The type `wchar_t` was put into the standard when Unicode promised to create a 16 bit representation. Most vendors choose to make `wchar_t` 32 bits but one large vendor has chosen to to make it 16 bits. Since Unicode uses more than 16 bits (e.g., 20 bits) it was felt that we should have better character types.

The intent for `char16_t` is to represent UTF16 and `char32_t` is meant to directly represent Unicode characters. However, on systems using `wchar_t` as part of their fundamental interface, you'll be stuck with `wchar_t`. If you are unconstrained I would personally use `char` to represent Unicode using UTF8. The problem with `char16_t` and `char32_t` is that they are not fully supported, not even in the standard C++ library: for example, there are no streams supporting these types directly and it more work than just instantiating the stream for these types.

Comment: Is the lack of support for `char16_t` and `char32_t` in the standard due to the standard stating no such support or is it due to the types being new, meaning the support will come with time?

Comment: @user904963: The current revision doesn't mandate names for the `char16_t` and `char32_t` versions. It seems it does mandate the necessary facets, however, which means the streams could be used. I haven't seen proposals improving the support but that doesn't mean the committee is objecting to adding support, i.e., it may come.

Comment: Complete char16_t and char32_t support never arrived.