# What does pointer sign represent in argument specification for ex: (char16 *buffer, int32 size)? C++

Tags: c++, syntax

Very simply beginner c++ question. I am reading a specification manual for an SDK and it has these pointer signs in the argument specifications. What do they represent?

So if a constructor takes `(char 16 * buffer, int32 size)` as arguments what do I need to actually input to the first argument to not get an error?

Comment: `char 16` is not a valid type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"pointer sign"*. Do you expect pointers to be signed integers? Do you mean the sign of `size`, since it's a signed integer? Do you mean to call the asterisk the "pointer sign"?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm pretty sure he means "pointer symbol".

Comment: Do you mean `wchar`? If you're asking questions like this that's fine, but it's also a sign you need a good C++ reference. You should have the [official C++ book by the language's author](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) as well as some others that help explain other aspects of usage and best practices.

Comment: @tadman He probably means `char16_t`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068748/char-vs-wchar-t-vs-char16-t-vs-char32-t-c11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer indicates a location in memory rather than being a data type itself:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

If you have a constructor with the signature you gave above, then you need a pointer to an appropriately sized memory region for the first argument, and presumably you give it the size of the memory region for the second argument. Read your documentation carefully- that second argument might mean the size as in "number of elements" or it might mean size as in "number of bytes".

Asking a more specific question with the actual SDK and function might get you better results.