# Totally confused about reading UTF8 file under linux

Tags: linux, c++11, utf-8, unicode-string

I want to read linux UTF8 file char by char. I wanted to use wifstream:

```
std::wifstream wi("file");
wi.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(""), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
```

And read it with wchar_t:

```
for(wchar_t c; wi.get(c);) {
    std::wcout << c;
}
```

But after reading this: [char vs wchar_t vs char16_t vs char32_t (c++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068748/char-vs-wchar-t-vs-char16-t-vs-char32-t-c11) I'm totaly confused.

- What should I use char, char16_t, char32_t
- Should I use ifstream or wifstream
- Should I use new std::codecvt_utf8
- How I can extract single 'character' from file

My goal is to read file 'char' by 'char' and put each 'characted' to vector:

```
'vector<?>':
std::vector<?> chars;
for(? c; wi.get(c);) {
     chars.push_back(c);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? Also, what is a "linux UTF8 file"? UTF-8 has nothing specifically to do with Linux.

Comment: By character I mean what I need to put in vector. I meant UTF8 file under linux.

Comment: "*By character I mean what I need to put in vector.*" That tells me absolutely nothing, without knowing what you plan on doing with that vector. Do you want UTF-8 code units, code points, grapheme clusters, what?

Comment: So I want to keep code points in vector, then I want to use that code points to print actual characters.